# Improvement Suggestion for Color Measurement Algorithm

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, colors

I'm working on an Image Processing project for a while, which consists in a way to measure and classify some types of sugar in the production line by its color. Until now, my biggest concern was searching and implementing the appropriate mathematical techniques to calculate distance between two colors (a reference color and the color being analysed), and then, turn this value into something more meaningful, as an industry standard measure.

From this, I'm trying to figure out how should I reliably extract the average color value from an image, once the frame captured by a video camera may contain noises or dirt in the sugar (most likely almost black dots).

**Language:** Java with OpenCV library.

**Current solution:** Before taking average image value, I'm applying the *fastNlMeansDenoisingColored* function, provided by OpenCV. It removes some white dots, at cost of more defined details. Couldn't remove black dots with it (not shown in the following images).

[image: Image Sample before denoising function.]

[image: Image Sample after denoising function.]

From there, I'm using the *org.opencv.core.Core.mean* function to computate the mean value of array elements independently for each channel, so that I can have a scalar value to use in my calculations.

I tried to use some kinds of image thresholding filters to get rid of black and white dots, and then calculate the mean with a mask, It kinda works too. Also, I tried to find any weighted average function which could return scalar values as well, but without success.

I don't know If those are robust enough pre-processing techniques to such application, mean values can vary easily. Am I in the right way? Would you suggest a better way to get reliable value that will represent my sugar's color?

Comment: what is color amount? I don't think it's making much sense to speak of color here at all. and I don't see why you need these filters and preprocessing at all. just exclude extreme pixel values from your evaluation.

Comment: I meant the sugar's color, sorry, nvm about color "amount". So, yeah, I do not disagree with you, that's why I'm asking, I'm just wondering If there is a better option like a filter to smooth minor pixels variations or If I should only exclude extreme pixels values with a threshold. Well, I'll take It as your answer and wait to see If someone has another advice :) thanks!

Comment: you're basically interested in the ratio between 3 channels. so you should make sure that no channel is saturated and that your signal to noise ratio is reasonable. most important thing here is to avoid any drifts so having a reference target or any other kind of feedback wouldn't hurt.